# Python f.write function

Tags: python, fwrite

What will this program write on the second line?

```
username = "Mo\nty"

password = "Py\thon"

f = open("andmed.txt", "w")

f.write("username:" + username + "\n")

f.write("password:" + password)

f.close()
```

Comment: Well why don't you run it and see what it writes?

Comment: Because I have to answer that question and I have no idea how to run it. As I said I'm new. I've learned Python for a month or so

Comment: Then maybe you should go through the [beginner's guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) first

Comment: is it "password:Py\thon"? No?

Comment: No, notice how it writes `parool`? What is `parool` defined to be? As far as I can tell this code will throw an exception.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, "parool" is password in estonian. Forgot to change it. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The \n and \t characters are interpreted as linefeed and tab respectively
So, the output would be as follows:

username:Mo
ty
password:Py         hon